# Fujitsu Lifebook AH544 Touch Pad Not Working In Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, fujitsu-siemens

Fujitsu Lifebook AH544 Touch Pad Not Working In Ubuntu 14.04, resolved.

Made in Germany Laptop
Intel Core i3-4000M processor (2.4 GHz, 3MB)
4 GB DDR3
500GB SATA, S.M.A.R.T.
15.6"DOS1 Year Onsite Warranty

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution from Arch Linux Forum, here is the link.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148115

To get the touchpad working I had to append

```
i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux
```

to the kernel boot parameters.

```
/etc/default/grub
```

**Commands**

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then find this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Extend the line with adding the above mentioned kernel boot parameter like below.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux"
```

Then update the rub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reeboot the system, Cheers!

Comment: can you provide me with a solution for fedora?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my Fujitsu Lifebook A series with Ubuntu 14.04:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux"
```