# Synaptic Touchpad Not Working After 18.04LTS Clean Install

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I have a dual Win10 boot and (K)ubuntu 18.04 on a Fujitsu Ultrabook UH572 i5/8GBram and (K)ubuntu is running on a 32GBSSD. After a clean install of (K)ubuntu 18.04 I noticed that the touchpad wasn't working...*On Win everything works fine.*

It's the first time I'm running Ubuntu on this machine so I don"t know what the issue could be. In the past I never had an issue with the touchpad. Maybe it has to do with the fact that its a click-touch-pad? It has no buttons just a big area, kind like a Mac.....

In any case I can see the touchpad when typing **xinput list** in terminal. 
Below the output:

```
kongking@UH572:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera: FJ Camera                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've tried editing the **etc/default/grub** file and replacing "quiet splash" with "acpi=force", according the link below: 
[SynPS/2 Synaptic Touchpad not working in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991080/synps-2-synaptic-touchpad-not-working-in-ubuntu-17-10), with no luck.

Any ideas how to tackle this??

Sorry if I misuse the Forum and your time, with an Kubuntu question but whenever I have a problem I search at Ubuntu solutions....and to be honest I couldn't find a more relevant site.

Many thanks,
μρ .

Answer (score 0):

Solved guys.....

Had to add in the boot options (etc/default/grub):

**i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux**

according this source:
[Fujitsu Lifebook AH544 Touch Pad Not Working In Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533903/fujitsu-lifebook-ah544-touch-pad-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)

μρ .